# Please Explain me this C code

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Can some one please help me on understanding this code especially the 'space' part. How is value of space in spite being 4 printing no space in the first row of the output of this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Inverted mirrored right triangle */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, space;

    for (i = 0; i <= 5 ;i++) {
        for (space = 5 - i; space <= 4; space++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (j = 5 - i; j >= 0; j--) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We are not a tutoring site.

Comment: Write the value of each variable on a piece of paper; or print them; or use a debugger.

Comment: If `space = 5 - i`, what is `space` when `i == 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

concentrate on this piece of code

```
for (i = 0; i <= 5 ;i++) {
    --> for (space = 5 - i; space <= 4; space++) {
          printf(" ");
    }
```

in first iteration of inner for loop space value is `space: 5-0 = 5` 
as the `i:0` and for we have condition `space <= 4` and this not satisfy control does not
go in to the inner of for braces and not print any space (for first row)

you must know how the `for(;;)` works.

```
for (i=0 ; i<10 ; i++ ) {
   printf("%d",i);
}
// end loop line

for (loop index initialize  ; condition ; do after innerloop commands ) {
   command1;
   command2;
}
```

first of all `i:0` and because `i` is less than 10 inner of loop executes
and print 0 on screen.
after printing `i` are incremented by one (`i++` equals to `i = i+1`).
then `i:1` , `i` still less than 10 and print `i:1`, wee see 1 on screen and so 
on. until we have `i:9` print 9 on screen then increase by one i:10
then last iteration come, as now `i:10` and is not less than 10 the inner of 
loop not execute, program control comes to after loop (end loop line).